# Show that $\psi(n)$ has finitely many roots

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, roots, special-functions

Define $\psi(n)=\pi(n)-\phi(n)$ where we have the prime counting function and totient function respectively.

I'm interested in where $\psi(n)=0$.

Specifically is it possible to prove that there are exactly $9$ roots, namely for $n=0,2,3,4,8,10,14,20,90$. I calculated these roots but I couldn't find any more.

I think this function has finitely many roots because the totient function grows faster and thus becomes greater than the prime counting function at a certain threshold.

Thanks for your help. I'm not sure how simple or how difficult this is to prove, and I appreciate any ideas and hints.

Comment: Indeed, the ratio explodes and tells you that there are only finitely many solutions. On wikipedia you find upper and lower bounds for those two functions. I would give it a try to see what kind of threshold you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, [Rosser and Schoenfeld](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ijm/1255631807) showed (formulas 3.41 and 3.42) that $\phi$ (which is, on average, linear) is never much worse than that: namely
$$ \phi(n) \geq \frac{n}{e^\gamma \log \log n + \frac{2.50637}{\log \log n}}  $$ 
Here the logarithm is base $e$ and the constant $2.50637$ chosen to give equality at (and only at)
$$ n = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13 \cdot 17 \cdot 19 \cdot 23 = 223092870 $$

There are also upper bounds on $\pi(x),$ for example formula 3.2.